# SQL Server FullText search for phrase containing punctuation, e.g. IP address?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm using SQL Server fulltext to search text in large varchar/varbinary columns that may contain IP addresses.  I understand that the dots in the address aren't in the index, but I thought a phrase search such as this would work:

select * from myFTETable where contains(myFTEcolumn, "192 168 100 101")

It doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to search for IP addresses, or more generally is there a way to do a phrase search when the phrase in the original data contains punctuation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the [LIKE operator doesn't take advantage of the fulltext index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#like) resulting in long query runtimes as your database grows.

Have you tried querying the internal index table to see what numbers are being indexed? This can be accomplished by running -

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(db_id('{database}'), object_id('{table}'))
```

Inserting 192.168.100.101 in a full-text indexed table shows up as 8-distinct entries internally(4 numeric, 4 character) and running a CONTAINS('"192 168 100 101"') brings up the relevant row.

As a caveat, fulltext will strip some of the lower numbers as part of its stoplists mechanism. This can be overridden by specifying STOPLIST OFF during index creation or removing the matching strings from the internal stoplist.